# d3: Contour or Surface plot from Irregular/Scattered Data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I can take a set of triplets [X,Y,Z] and immediately generate a (smooth) contour plot using Python and matplotlib with a **single call** to [tricontour()](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tricontour_demo.html).  One can also generate contours 'easily' using [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/python/contour-plots/), but I find it to be unacceptably slow. (Also, I'm not interested in the [MATLAB solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125475/plot-surface-from-irregular-data), which is similar to the Python)

**I'm looking for similar functionality using d3.js.**  I would settle for a "surface plot" instead of contours, or a "heat map" without contour lines.

I can see how to generate a [colored Delaunay triangulation](http://bl.ocks.org/codybuell/0580aced13cfa71de0ff) and/or a [colored Voronoi Tesselation](http://colored%20Voronoi%20Tesselation), but the question of [how to generate a contour plot in d3 from irregular data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127518/contour-plot-from-scattered-data-in-javascript) seems to still be an open one (even though the question on this was prematurely closed!).

So far, all I've seen are approaches "by hand", using [Radial basis functions (gaussian blur)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313761/d3-js-3d-array-interpolation) or grid interpolation using [Barycentric interpolation](http://bl.ocks.org/jackielii/d3523c9116e5d3b45ec3d8aa76fb1f57).

I'd even be willing to 'live with' Gouraud-shading or Coon-gradients on a Delaunay triangulation, but apparently ["advanced shading methods" like Gourand or Coon gradients are not in "regular" SVG but are proposed for SVG2](http://www.svgopen.org/2011/papers/18-Advanced_Gradients_for_SVG/)...not sure where that leaves me with d3 & (regular) SVG.  It seems like [doing this SVG gradient-shading by hand](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=3398) would be a major pain.

**Is there a "better" package-y way to do this, i.e. something that doesn't require so much 'custom' code?**  (Maybe via some multidimensional Bezier routine I haven't found yet?)

I'll post a Fiddle with my starting point: a colored Voronoi tesselation: https://jsfiddle.net/k2v2jy7s/1/.  Can you help me take this from "blocky" to "smooth" (and maybe even show contour lines)?

```
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height");

    var npoints = 1000;
    var sites = d3.range(npoints)
        .map(function(d) { return [Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height]; });


    // values  at data points / colors being mapped = "zvals"
    var kx = 3.14159/(width*0.5);
    var ky = 3.14159/(height*0.5);
    var zvals = d3.range(npoints)
    for (i = 0; i < npoints; i++) { 
        zvals[i] = (1.0 + Math.cos(kx*sites[i][0]) * Math.cos(ky*sites[i][1]))/2.0;
        zvals[i] *= zvals[i];
    }

    var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0+ "," + 0 + ")");

    var voronoi = d3.voronoi()
        .extent([[-1, -1], [width + 1, height + 1]]);

    var polygon = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "polygons")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(voronoi.polygons(sites))
        .enter().append("path")
        .style('fill', function(d,i){ return d3.hsl( zvals[i]*310,        1, .5); })
        .call(redrawPolygon);

    function redrawPolygon(polygon) {
      polygon
          .attr("d", function(d) { return d ? "M" + d.join("L") + "Z" : null; });
    }
</script>
```

*Update*: Also found this blocks.org post on ["Gradient Heatmaps"](https://bl.ocks.org/diafygi/35b7b52cba267cf9c5f4), which as I mentioned is the sort of result I'd be willing to live with, but again that's a large quantity of custom code.  Would really prefer a compact 'stock' solution, a la  tricontour().

Answer (score 0):

5 ½ years, and no answers to this question!

Well, I've also been looking into how to generate contours from a series of `[X,Y,Z]` points in Javascript, but have not yet found the best or most complete solution. A lot of solutions I came across via Googling (such as [d3-contour](https://github.com/d3/d3-contour)) are designed for an evenly spaced grid of values, not an irregular series of points as you might obtain from a land survey.

#### d3-tricontour

The **[d3-tricontour](https://github.com/Fil/d3-tricontour)** library looks perhaps the most promising, though, so I might have a play around with it.

Here's an example of what it can generate:

[image: d3-tricontour library example]

(The labels are optional.)

[Apparently](https://observablehq.com/@fil/tricontours) it uses the [delaunay](https://github.com/d3/d3-delaunay) and [meandering triangles](https://blog.bruce-hill.com/meandering-triangles) algorithms to convert arbitrary points into triangles and then contour geometry. The algorithm works in O(n) where n is the number of edges, meaning it's very fast and scales perfectly well.

To learn more you can visit their:

- [Github repository](https://github.com/Fil/d3-tricontour)
- [Many examples on Observable](https://observablehq.com/collection/@fil/tricontours)

#### Alternatives

Otherwise, there might be other ways to do this. If working with one of the grid-based libraries, I think the general process would be to:

1. Convert arbitary `[X,Y,Z]` points into a grid — the Delaunay algorithm is probably a great place to start (see [d3-delaunay](https://github.com/d3/d3-delaunay) or [other delaunay libraries](https://github.com/topics/delaunay?l=javascript))
2. Find the Z value for each point in the grid using some kind of interpolation (the maths for that, I'm not sure about)
3. Then feed that result into one of the grid-based contouring libraries

#### Constraining Contours

Also take note that creating contours from real world terrain also requires "*constraining*" some edges so that contours don't crossover ridgelines where they shouldn't.

[CDT-JS](https://savithru-j.github.io/cdt-js/) is a <strike>library</strike> web app (with no separate library available as yet) that calculates *constrained* Delaunay triangulation, which might be useful for this case.

Otherwise, in theory, you might be able to create this kind of functionality by injecting additional `[X,Y,Z]` points along your lines of contraint prior to rendering. But I haven't tested this approach.